# i am having problems when i try access localhost wordpress site from mobile

Tags: wordpress, apache

i am designing my wordpress website in my localhost with using wampp 3.1.7 (apache 2.4.38) and i tried reach my project from mobile.

i read stackoverflow topics and applied steps one by one :

> -added 8080 port in my firewall "incoming rules"

edited rooter NAT with my ip : 192.168.0.xx and port 8080
i changed apache httpd.conf like :

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080



<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>

onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted

ServerName localhost:8080
```

and edited httpd-vhosts like :

```
# Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything work well localhost:8080/mysite or 192.168.1.xx/mysite work well too.wampp systemtry icon is glowing green with red dot. its online and working well too.

when i try enter 192.168.1.xx from my phone i am entering wamppserver settings.but if i add /mysite (192.168.1.xx) i had error localhost refused to connect. (err_connection_refused)

tried everything but didn't get the result.sorry for my bad language..

1 more question..how can i open that server everyone for share my website design with friends to get feedback its possible ?

Comment: Can you please format your httpd.conf configuration it's not clear !

Comment: yes it looks better now i think.sorry for that